# How can i check if strings are equal without using the eq operator ( == / ~=)

Tags: lua

my idea is the convert the 2 strings into byte, subtract and then check if they're 0 using a for loop like this

```
function match(str1, str2, callback)
    local res = string.byte(str1) - string.byte(str2)
    for i = 1, res(0) do
        spawn(callback)
    end
end
```

but that just doesn't work can anyone write me a code would appreciate...

Comment: I mean... you *can* do it, but why would you?

Answer (score 0):

```lua
rawequal(str1, str2) -- Compares two values without calling any metamethods
```

Comment: What do you mean trying not to get cracked? You'll need to provide more context than that

Comment: rawequal actually worked fine, but im still very interested if there are ways to do this without using == / ~= operators

Comment: rawequal works, but exploiters in roblox are still able to use hookfunction(rawset, function() end) and exploit my game, please just give me the answer

Comment: If someone can hook into any function, then of course you can't. That's bad design though, I'm quite surprised that they would actually do that.

Comment: Please add a few sentences to explain what your code is doing, so you can get more upvotes for your answer.

Comment: @FuzzyAnalysis `rawequal()` does exactly what the name says, no magic behind the scenes or anything.

Comment: The documentation has this to say about it: `Checks whether v1 is equal to v2, without invoking the __eq metamethod. Returns a boolean.` That's barely anything beyond what I explain in the comment.